# JavaFX onShowing Stage after fxml is loaded

Tags: javafx, stage

what im trying to do is a javaFX window that handles my code **while** my window is shown so i worked on

```
public void setStage()(Stage stage){
this.stage = stage;
stage.setonShowing(new EventHandler<WindowEvent>() {
    @Override
    public void handle(WindowEvent event) {
        work();   //What i want to do while my window is visible
    }
});
stage.show();
}
```

setStage() gets his Stage from the class where i load my fxml from....

Everytime my window is popping up the sleep is **before** the fxml is loaded but **after** the window showed up so i only have a white window with nothing on it

To be honest im not sure what the real problem is

is it that i sleep before the fxml is loaded or is it my setonShowing() which is not working as it should be?
i also tryed to use `setonShown()` instead of  `setonShowing()` but nothing changed

what i also tryed is to override the `setonShowing` in my Parent class but that also didnt work

so to make sure i didnt made anything wrong with my fxml here is the code i use to creat the window:

```
        Parent root;
        Stage stage = (Stage) StartSingleplayer_B.getScene().getWindow();
        stage.close(); // closing my old window

        try {

            fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("Spielfeld.fxml"));
            root = (Parent) fxmlLoader.load();
            GameController controller = fxmlLoader.getController();
            Stage stage2 = new Stage();
            controller.setStage(stage2);
            stage2.setOnShowing(new EventHandler<WindowEvent>() {
                @Override
                public void handle(WindowEvent event) {
                    work();
                }
            });
            stage2.setScene(new Scene(root));
            stage2.show();
        } catch(Exception e) {

            e.printStackTrace();

        }
```

i really appreaciate your help so it would be nice if someone could give me a clue what i did wrong and / or how i could fix it

Comment: Don't block the javafx application thread with something like sleep. It pervents layout and proper rendering.

Comment: Okay but what should i do instead? I have to implement a delay... im currently trying timer but there are so many obstacles i need to overcome